# The wisdom of 'server 127.127.1.0' in ntp.conf for virtual servers

Tags: puppet, ntp

Considering the 'undisciplined local clock' on VMs is not what you'd call accurate in most cases, how wise is it to include lines such as these in your NTP configuration?

```
# Undisciplined Local Clock. This is a fake driver intended for backup
# and when no outside source of synchronized time is available.
server  127.127.1.0     # local clock
fudge   127.127.1.0 stratum 10
```

In my case the ntp config is managed through puppet and we are pushing real NTP servers at it. However, it looks like this fake-server may be causing some servers to take longer to get in sync with the rest of the network.

Are these lines doing anything *useful* in this case, or are they safe to remove?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have real NTP servers available, those lines are doing nothing useful and should be removed.